# \indexsetup{othercode=\FONTSIZE} Not Changing Fontsize with Idxlayout

Tags: fontsize, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\Large

A sentence.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[3]}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

And the index generated by it:

[image]

As one can see, the Index fontsize is not `footnotesize`.

QUESTION: Can anyone point out what I may be doing wrong with this approach? it seems to me that the code as is should work.

Comment: I can get properly working code if I ignore the `\indexsetup` command and replace `\usepackage{idxlayout}` by `\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}`, but I would like to know why the `\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}` command is not working in the above code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove `idxlayout` I get the expected result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex[columns=1]
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
A sentence.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[3]}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need `idxlayout` you need the proper syntax:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex
\idxlayout{columns=1,font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
A sentence.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}!\textbf{Subheading}!\lipsum[3]}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: An observation: It seems that there is a limit to the size of the font in `\idxlayout{columns=1,font=footnotesize}`; if I change `footnotesize` to, say, `large`, I get an error. Do you know if this is supposed to happen?

Comment: @SamuelBowditch Looking at the code of `idxlayout` style, I see that the only accepted options for `font` are `current`, `normalsize`, `small` or `footnotesize`. With the “only `imakeidx` approach you can set whatever font size you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your comment.