# Looking for an Optimal Way to Change the Font Size of Index Entries Only (Not Headings or Subheadings)

Tags: fontsize, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

This post is a bit of an extension of the one posed in [\indexsetup{othercode=\FONTSIZE} Not Changing Fontsize with Idxlayout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623600/indexsetupothercode-fontsize-not-changing-fontsize-with-idxlayout)

When one specifies an index font size with `idxlayout` as such: `\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}`, the heading, subheading, and entry content all seem to get adjusted accordingly. Consider,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
%\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

A sentence.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined amid his books, shut up from all mankind, and sees the world scarce on a holiday, as through a telescope and far away---How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, to bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which outputs the Index:

[image]

I would like to be able to adjust the font size for the entry content only, keeping the Heading and Subheading scaled according to `\Large` which is specified in the code following the preamble.

But I have not found a way to do this automatically.

So, I manipulated the code a bit by not specifying the font size in the preamble and forcing the font size of the entry content to be `normalsize` ---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
%\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

A sentence.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{\normalsize{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined amid his books, shut up from all mankind, and sees the world scarce on a holiday, as through a telescope and far away---How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, to bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which now gives scaled `Large` font sizes for the heading and subheading, and a `normalsize` font for the entry content---But---some very large spacing between the lines of the content, which was not present in the original output:

[image]

QUESTION: Is there an automatic way to specify the font size of the entry content *only*, keeping the spacing between the lines the same as that shown in the first output above? If not, is there a manual way to do this (such as I attempted with in second set of code) but keeping the spacing between the lines similar to that displayed in the first index above? Of course, an automatic approach is preferable; otherwise, I one would likely have to make numerous manual adjustments in an actual document.

Thank you.

Comment: `\normalsize{..}` font sizes never take an argument, and should have end of paragraph in scope to set the line spacing, so `{\normalsize ...\par}` (but you shouldn't have font sizes in the index entries

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comment and the `\par`  suggestion. If it's not too much trouble, would you elaborate a little as to why I shouldn't have font sizes in the index? Many thanks again for your helpful comment.

Comment: @David Carlisle I have noticed the `\par` insertion takes care of the interline spacing problem, but it causes the page number to be displayed below the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This another possible solution keeping `idxlayout` capabilities. The command `\idxFont` will set the font size and shape.

**normalsize**

[image: a]

**footnotesize**

[image: b]

**Large**

[image: c]

**small, italic shape**

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{denim}{rgb}{0.08, 0.38, 0.74}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\usepackage{imakeidx}   
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

%**************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\idxFont}{} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{30\p@}\idxFont}
\makeatother
%**************************

\begin{document}

A sentence.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{ Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined amid his books, shut up from all mankind, and sees the world scarce on a holiday, as through a telescope and far away---How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, to bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex

\renewcommand{\idxFont}{\footnotesize}
\printindex

\renewcommand{\idxFont}{\Large}
\printindex 

\renewcommand{\idxFont}{\sffamily \small \color{denim}}
\printindex 

\renewcommand{\idxFont}{\itshape \small} 
\printindex 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting these answers. I noticed that you defined a color `burntorange` . Is there a reason why you chose this specific color or was it arbitrary? I noticed, however, that you did not make use of it. It might be a coincidence that is not obvious to users on this site, but I figured I'd ask anyway. In any case, thank you for your answers.

Comment: @mlchristians I was trying several colors but I ended up without putting the figures in the answer. I will correct the code so as not to confuse. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: No problem. I asked because I am using that *exact* color in the document I am working on and which is the basis for the question I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure quite what fonts you want but

[image]

`mcl2.ist` makindex style

```
item_0 "\n\\Large\\item"
item_1 "\n\\large\\subitem"
item_x1 "\n\\large\\subitem"
item_2 "\n\\normalsize\\subsubitem"
item_x2 "\n\\normalsize\\subsubitem"
```

and main document

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex[options=-s mcl2.ist]
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{idxlayout}
%\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\Large

A sentence.\index{GOETHE@\textbf{GOETHE'S \textit{FAUST}}!1@\textbf{\color{red}{Wagner}}!{Alack"! when a poor wight is so confined amid his books, shut up from all mankind, and sees the world scarce on a holiday, as through a telescope and far away---How may he hope, with nicely tempered skill, to bend the hearts he knows not to his will?}}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

An alternative of course is to do all the restyling in latex redefining `\item`, `\subitem` and `\subsubitem`, but then you need to coordinate with the packages you are using that are also making redefinitions.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This looks like it might be what I am looking for, but aside from you Main Document code, I don't know how to incorporate the `mcl2.ist` and the list of five `item_` s. I tried sandwiching the list between `\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\mcl2.ist}` and `\end{filecontents*}` before `\documentclass{book}` but that does not work. May I ask that you display how to incorporate `mcl2.ist` and the  list of `item_`s in one set of workable code please? Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians why do you need to make it written by the tex file? if you want that you can use filecontents as you show but with `{mcl2.ist}` not `{\mcl2.ist}`  but you can just save the file as a why put it in `filecontents` ?

Comment: I think I would need to specify it in the Tex file, for aren't they changeable font sizes you specify in the list of items? Isn't `mcl2.ist` a name you  gave for this solution and thus needs to be incorporated somehow in the Tex file? At least that's what I thought. If it's the name of a preexisting file then I can see how you can call it in with `options`; otherwise, I'm confused as to how the list of item specifications is called in if all I need to do is run your Main Document code. Please forgive my confusion.

Comment: it's the same as the last answer I posted, it's a style for makindex and the imakeindex package calls makeindex with that style if you specify it as I show here, look at the generated `.ind` file to see the effect of the style. Just save the file along with your tex file, there is no point in writing out the same fixed file every time